# RuntimeException when using VideoView in WebView - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, webview, android-webview, android-videoview

I know there are lot of questions asked around this topic but none of them helped me :(
I am trying to call a java method to play video in VideoView on passing a parameter through a WebView, but I am running into following issues:

1. In activity_main, when I have VideoView tag inside WebView then I am getting a blank black screen, basically my HTML is not getting loaded.
2. In activity_main, when I do not use VideoView but WebView only then my HTML gets displayed but I get Uncaught Error on instantiating the VideoView using VideoView vv = new VideoView( this ).
3. On using Relative or Linear Tag around WebView and VideoView tags not letting the application to start.

Can somebody help me in refining my activty_main.xml to get this code working? Please find below my code snippets:

My activity_main.xml:

```
    <WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
                  android:id="@+id/WebView123"     
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"      
                  android:layout_height="fill_parent"      
                  android:layout_weight="1.0"    >
              <!--On removing this VideoView, HTML getting displayed but Video not gettin launched
                  <VideoView android:id="@+id/videoView"
                  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                  />
                  </WebView>
```

My MainActivty.java

```
                         public class MainActivity extends Activity {

         WebView browser;

            @Override
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    browser = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.WebView123);
    WebSettings webSettings = browser.getSettings(); 
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    webSettings.setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON_DEMAND); 
    webSettings.setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);  
    browser.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());  
    browser.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(browser , String url) {
                return false;
                 }
                 });
                MainActivity jsInterface = new MainActivity();
    browser.addJavascriptInterface(jsInterface, "interfaces");
    browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
    setContentView(browser);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@JavascriptInterface
public void videoPlayer(String identifer){
    System.out.println("Hey I am in Here");
  // 2nd Point - >  VideoView videoHolder = new VideoView(this);
    VideoView videoHolder = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

    MediaController mc = new MediaController(this);
    mc.setAnchorView(videoHolder);
    videoHolder.setMediaController(mc);
    if(identifer.equals("1")){
        String path = "android.resource://" + R.raw.intro;
        videoHolder.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
         }
       videoHolder.start();
       videoHolder.requestFocus();
          }
              } //class end
```

My HTML for WebView:

```
                 <button onClick="window.interfaces.videoPlayer('1');">Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding approach #1, actually you cannot put `VideoView` within `WebView` as the latter is purely used to paint web pages.

Regarding approach #2, please note that `JavascriptInterface` is NOT executed in the Android UI main thread, as it's invoked from JS engine. i.e. If you have access to UI components (in your case, you manipulate `VideoView` via `findViewById()`), then you need to move this into the UI main thread. Because in Android some operations, especially view manipulations, are ONLY allowed to be executed in the UI main thread.

To be more specific, you may want to use [runOnUiThread()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29), or send an Intent to launch the video in your `MainActivty.java`.